# Why Are My Gridseed Blades Exploding? What Components Are Exploding?

Tags: mining-hardware, gridseed

I'm wanting to get into mining not so much for the mining reward but because I support the idea of decentralised currency and the power of peer to peer transactions.

However I have a problem with getting some Gridseed Blades up and running. Something on them is exploding. Please see the below photos.

---

This is my power supply unit.
[image: This is my Power Supply Unit]

---

I live in the UK so the voltage is set to 220V mode.
[image]

---

This is the front of the PSU wired up. My multimeter reads 12v coming from the output.
[image]

---

I'm in the middle of building a stack of blades but I need to overcome the problem of something in them exploding.
[image]

---

In this photo you can see there are three components that have exploded. What are these components? What would cause them to explode?
[image]

---

This photo is for comparison, this is a good blade where the components haven't exploded.
[image]

---

I've tried to look for a datasheet or a gridseed blade board schematic but I can't find one.

Every time I connect a blade to my power supply these same components explode. What could be causing this to happen and what could I do to stop this from happening?

Also I would like to repair the Gridseed Blades that have already exploded, is there a schematic for this board, or at least what are the components that have been damaged?

Answer (score 1):

So after [asking elsewhere](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1505024) I got half of my question answered. The reason the boards exploded was because the polarity of output was backwards. For some reason Gridseed supply power cables with the typical colours of red for live and white for ground reversed!

My solution was to swap the white and red wires over and I got no more explosions.

Does any one know what components have been damaged? And where would I get replacements from?

Answer (score 1):

> **Does any one know what components have been damaged?**

They look like 0 Ohm SMT (surface mount) resistors.

I can't tell the physical package size but they look relatively large.
I cant tell the power rating. You'd have to guess and hope for the best.

> **And where would I get replacements from?**

Any electronics supply business. For example [CPC](http://cpc.farnell.com/unbranded/mc-0-125w-1206-0r/resistor-1206-0r0/dp/RE03976)

You could also just use a solder link. The SMT resistors are probably being used as a kind of fuse.

It is possible the blown SMT resistors failed to protect other components on the PCB - you may have to diagnose and replace other failed parts.

Answer (score 1):

Those are just links, trivial to repair, but that's not the issue: If those have blown then it's all but certain that something else did as well. The good news is that the damaged circuit is easily recognisable as your basic SMPS, a very common field of electronics that any engineer or even decently skilled hobbyist can repair, and it's quite unlikely that anything other than the SMPS circuit was damaged, so the expensive miner chips should be fine. The bad news is that you are not an engineer or skilled hobbyist, so you'll have to find someone who is, ideally local. It should just be a matter of poking at it with a multimeter and oscilloscope to find the faults, and replacing them with readily-available spares - there are no exotic components in there.

When you're done, write an angry letter to the designers for their inexplicable decision to violate the polarity convention.

Answer (score 0):

another thing you should check is output dc voltages they don't like high voltages passed 12volts

i noticed maybe it's angle you have no heatsinks thats a no no for long term mining esp over clocking the speed  i tried oc even with heatsink and fan blowing and the heatsinks are screaming hot, and my heatsink stating to get that burn metal smell after short while

Answer (score -1):

I had A failed power supply unit from Bitman Sold by Bitman Ebay, they had A 100% feed back at the time & this was over A year ago, the power Supply was was running at more than the 10 amps they said the unit was rated for & the electric lines in my walls where hot, the cable they sent was under rated for the power draw, I used one rated for 45 amps for the power cable, their res once response was this is normal for are equipment, Ebay promptly gave A full refund after review, my advice is watch out what you are buying for mining or you can burn your place down

Comment: This doesn't answer the question